# Difference between `int* const& x` and `int* const x` in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I've read of the differences between passing by value, passing by reference, and passing (a pointer) by constant reference, yet I'm don't understand the difference between the latter, and just passing a constant pointer. As an example, what is the difference between

```
int PI = 3;

int* getArg(int* const& x){
    x = &PI;
    return x;
}

int main() {

}
```

and

```
int PI = 3;

int* getArg(int* const x){
    x = &PI;
    return x;
}

int main() {

}
```

Both of these cause the same `error: assignment of read-only parameter 'x'`.

Comment: You get the error because the pointer `x` is constant and you can't modify it. `int* const x` can be read as "`x` is a constant pointer to a (non-constant) `int`".

Comment: Yes, but is that not also how we are to read `int* const& x`?

Comment: Why would you use such a thing? `const int* x` (const pointer) or `const int& x` (const reference) or possibly `int&` (mutable reference) are the the common forms. There's an infinite number of other forms that really don't serve any particular purpose. Is the goal to have a read-only argument, or a mutable one?

Comment: What textbook is this and why would they inflict that on you? In modern C++ code you try and avoid pointers in favour of references whenever possible. With pointers *and* references you're going to make a mess of things, there's absolutely no need unless you're manipulating the pointer via a reference, in which case `const` does not apply.

Comment: in the context of teaching material it can make sense, if accompanied with some explanation, but in the wild I would consider  `int* const& x` an obfuscation that needs to be fixed

Comment: Yes it's the same with `int* const& x`, it begins "`x` is a reference to a..." but other wise the same. And no there's no real difference between the two. Passing a pointer by reference only makes sense if you intend to change where it's pointing.

Comment: *"I'm just wondering if removing the & can be done without altering the code"* - by definition removing `&` is altering the code, so I'm not sure I understand what you mean. And removing it won't solve the `x = ` dilemma regardless, as you've discovered.

Comment: @tadman Oh my mistake, I did not read such code from the book but from some [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-use-const-with-reference-to-a-pointer-in-c/#:~:text=Const%20Reference%20to%20a%20pointer,same%20as%20a%20const%20pointer.&text=Here%20we%20get%20a%20compile,not%20allowed%20to%20reassign%20it.&text=It%20prints%20100%20as%20it,a%20pointer%20of%20a%20const.) online.

Comment: that explains a lot.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was wondering @Someprogrammerdude. I would upvote the comment but apparantely I'm too new to do that.

Comment: Oh Geeks for Geeks. You should stop reading that website. It's known for bad code style, wrong information and mistakes.

Comment: @ThomasSablik It's showing up a lot in search results lately and the answers are usually pretty awful, like if anyone knew what they were talking about they were too pressed for time to explain themselves clearly.

Comment: for their defense, that site you link is only telling you what you can do with const references / pointers. It is not about why and when to use them, in particular it is not about passing parameters to functions. Though I agree with Thomas, it is already exceptional to find code that is actual (portable, standard) C++ code on that site.

Answer (score 2):

If you're clear on passing variables by value and by reference, then try breaking down complex types into parts to help make sense of what's going on:

```cpp
using PointerToInt = int*;
using ConstPointerToInt = PointerToInt const;

int* getArg_v1(ConstPointerToInt x) {
    x = &PI;  // it's const by value so you're not allowed to change it
    return x;
}

int* getArg_v2(ConstPointerToInt& x) {
    x = &PI;  // it's const by reference so you're not allowed to change it
    return x;
}
```